# Como eliminar un objeto de un array sin usar ninguna función de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Como puedo eliminar un objeto de un array sin usar ninguna función como splice, pop, filter, delete, etc?

Comment: ¿qué sentido tiene?!!

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurren dos formas, que podrán ser aplicables o no según lo que quieras hacer:

- Reducir el tamaño del array eliminará los últimos elementos:

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log('Antes de reducir:',array.toString());

array.length = 4;

console.log('Después de reducir:',array.toString());
```

- Poner valores `null` o `undefined` en las posiciones que quieras eliminar, pero esto no reducirá la longitud del array:

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log('Antes de reducir:',array.toString());

array[6] = null;
array[5] = undefined;
//hay comas separando los elementos vacíos al final
console.log('Después de reducir:',array.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

A demás de los métodos que menciona @pablo-lozano también puedes usar bucles tradicionales si sabes que elemento es el que quieres eliminar:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const toDelete = 4;
let newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const el = arr[i];
  if (el !== toDelete) {
    newArr.push(el);
  }  
}

console.log(`El nuevo array contiene ${newArr}`);


// O usando un for-of

const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const toDelete2 = 4;
let newArr2 = [];
for (let el of arr2) {
  if (el !== toDelete) {
    newArr2.push(el);
  }  
}

console.log(`El nuevo array contiene ${newArr2}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podes usar el operador de propagacion `...` dejando lugares vacios para las posiciones que no queres, va a ser util para las primeras posiciones del array ya que el operador de propagacion es lo ultimo que podes poner porque toma el resto

```js
let array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let [,...TodosMenosElPrimero] = array
array=TodosMenosElPrimero
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de esta forma :D

```js
var lista = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Wilmer Delgado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Maria Garcia"
  }
]

function eliminar(id){
  let z = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < lista.length;i++){
    let x = lista[i]
    if(x.id != id){
      z.push(x)
    }
  }
  lista = z
  console.log(lista)
}

eliminar(1)
```